# Intellisense doesn't work on one of c# projects in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

I wanted to open C# .Net Core project in Visual Studio, but unfortunately Intellisense doesn't seem to work properly, It highlights errors, but only when I build project. `F12` (go to definition) doesn't work, as well as context specific suggestions.

**What is strange: it works on other projects, but not this specific one.**

C# Extensions I use in Visual Studio Code:
[C#](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.csharp) and [C# extensions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jchannon.csharpextensions) (I'm not sure which one enables intellisense)

There is an error in OmniSharp log:

> [ERROR] Error: OmniSharp server load timed out. Use the 'omnisharp.projectLoadTimeout' setting to override the default delay (one minute).

But probably doesn't mean anything important.

I have currently `.Net Core 1.1.0` installed, but project I want to open probably uses other version:

`global.json`

```
{
  "sdk": { "version": "1.0.0-preview2-1-003177" }
}
```

As far as I know, Intellisense should start working if `project.json` is available in folder. In my case: it is.

What could go wrong? What should I check to see why it doesn't work?

Comment: OmniSharp is what handles intellisense in VSCode, so that error is probably very important to the root cause of your issue.  Is this a larger project or does it have a lot of dependecies?

Comment: @JohnKoerner I'm trying to open exacty this folder in VSCode https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/tree/dev/templates/Angular2Spa

Answer (score 1):

A while ago I had a similar problem, and I resolved that deleting the ***Project.sln***, so you delete the configuration of your project, then you open this from ***project.csproj***.

If it is not useful for you, you could try with the ***unsafe mode***, open project properties, select *Build* tab and click on *Allow unsafe code*.